# Loading text file onto MySQL - skip first row

Tags: mysql, perl

I am loading the contents of a text file into a MySQL database. I have correctly loaded the table, but I haven't been able to skip the first line which is simply the table heading.

Here's the code I have written taking into account all of the comments on this thread. I added the line

```
if($. == 1) {
```

after I opened the file to skip the header of my text file but it still seems to not be working.

Thanks for your patience everyone.

Any suggestions?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use DBI;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my $user = shift @ARGV or die $!;
my $password = shift @ARGV or die $!;
my $database = shift @ARGV or die $!;
my $recipient_ewes = shift @ARGV or die $!;


my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$database:localhost",
                   $user,
                   $password,
                   {RaiseError => 1}
                   );



open (FILE, "rid.txt") or die $!;

while (<FILE>) {

    if($. == 1) {
        next;
    }

    my $GID;
    my $RID;
    my $number;

    my $line = $_;
    chomp $line;

    my @array = split("\t",$line);

    if (scalar(@array)==4){
        $RID = $array[0];
        $GID = $array[2];
        $number = $array[3];

        my $sth = $dbh-> prepare (qq{insert into $recipient_ewes (GID, RID,     numbertransferred) values ("$GID", "$RID", "$number")});

        $sth -> execute ();
        $sth -> finish ();
    }
}

$dbh->disconnt ();
exit;
close FILE;
```

The input file is:

```
Recipient ID            Round            Group #            # of transfers  
6507                      1                 2                     4  
5101                      1                 4                     4  
5007                      1                 5                     3  
6535                      2                 6                     4  
6510                      2                 7                     4
```

Comment: `next if $. == 1;` immediately after `while (...) {`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, and I tried putting that in multiple spots. What is that command supposed to do?

Comment: It does work, but without a [mcve], it's impossible to help you further.

Comment: You can read up on perl's special variables like `$.` [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).  `$.` contains the line number of your current file handle.  This page will also tell you why you shouldn't use `$1`, `$2`, etc. Search for `$<digits>` on the page.  I agree with @MattJacob that you need to edit your question to have a usable chunk of code if you want more help.

Comment: You appear to be trying to insert data into a table called `$recipient`, but you have declared no such variable; there is only the hash `%recipient`.

Comment: Are your column names really called `1`, `2` and `3`? They're very unusual and non-descriptiive names for data fields.

Comment: What do you think `$1 = $1` does? What do you think `push @array` does? (It will generate a warnings *Useless use of push with no values*).

Comment: I just posted the actual code in its entirety. I apologize about the confusion. I tried adding the if($. == 1) line but still am not getting it to work. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The entire file is not the same thing as a [mcve]. Please read the page that I'm linking to (here, once more: [mcve]) and then [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: It should be fairly obvious that we can't reproduce the problem without having access to your input data, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the database stuff, here's how to skip the first line when reading a file:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    next if $. == 1;
    my ($RID, undef, $GID, $number) = split;
    print join(', ', $RID, $GID, $number), "\n";
}

__DATA__
Recipient ID            Round            Group #            # of transfers
6507                      1                 2                     4
5101                      1                 4                     4
5007                      1                 5                     3
6535                      2                 6                     4
6510                      2                 7                     4
```

Output:

```
6507, 2, 4
5101, 4, 4
5007, 5, 3
6535, 6, 4
6510, 7, 4
```

Notes:

- [`$.`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24INPUT_LINE_NUMBER) is a special variable that refers to the current line number for the last filehandle accessed.
- [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) has a special whitespace mode when the pattern is omitted or a single space character.

Answer (score 4):

@Matt Jacob comment will solve your problem.

`$.` gives the current line number of the file.  [Here about next](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/next.html)

```
while (<$fh>)
{
   if($. == 1)  #@Matt Jacob written in one line
   {
      next;
   }

   # do your stuff

}
```

> > Always add `use warnings;` and `use strict;` in the top of the program.
> >
> > Use three argument for file handle.

**And then don't use `$1 $2 $3` as a variable name these will be used into the regex grouping.**

Finally as follow will help your problem

```
open my $fh, "<", "Filename.txt";
<$fh>; #Here removing the first line

while (my $line = <$fh>)
{
   chomp $line;
   ..
   do you stuff..
```